# Adding New Mesh Is not Working In Sculpting Mode!

Tags: mesh, sculpting

[image]I'm new in Blender, I tried using sculpting mode in Blender but the problem is when I added new mesh in the sculpting, the brushes are not working. but when I delete the added mesh it'll work again. Please can someone help me because I keep searching for it but I can't find any solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi! I just added my screenshots >< thank you so much!!

Comment: maybe the mesh you've added (the eye?) is a separate object, you can't sculpt 2 separate objects at the same time, you first need to join them (Ctrl J), they will still be 2 separate meshes, but within 1 object, and now you can sculpt both

Comment: oh yes! thank you so much!! I'll try to do that! I do really appreciate your help!!<3

Comment: You may also sometimes want to boolean 2 or more objects if you want the meshes to be kind of merged

Comment: How can I do that boolean 2??

Comment: I meant you can boolean 2 different objects or meshes. To boolean meshes: Merge the 2 objects with Ctrl J, switch to Edit mode, select one of the 2 meshes, then go into the head menu > Face > Intersect (Boolean)